# IE9 won't render @font-face truetype fonts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, font-face

IE9 won't render @font-face truetype fonts though all other browsers do. I'm getting the following exception:

```
CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must 
be Installable.
```

I found similar questions on here and other places, but none of the solutions provided worked for me. For example, adding the following in Web.config won't solve the problem.

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

There is also no woff version of the font I'm using, and I'm not sure if converting it into the woff format is allowed or not. I'm currently making an ASP.NET MVC project. How could I embed a ttf font in the project and use it in IE9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because IE doesn't support truetype so you need to convert it to .eot

Answer (score 0):

You should consult the owner of the font's copyrights to provide an installable version of the font or to send you the same font in an other format.

The other thing you can ask for is to give permission for you to make modifications. In this case I would recommend the full version of [**Fontlab Studio 5**](http://www.fontlab.com/buy): install the program, open the ttf file, choose the "Font Info... Ctrl+Alt+F" from the "File" menu, expand the "Names and Copyright" item in the left panel, select the "Embedding" item, then set the "Embedding settings (**fsType**):" to "**Everything is allowed (installable mode)**", press "OK", "File", "Generate Font... Ctrl+Alt+G", press "Save".

If you can't use Fontlab Studio 5, you can try any of the tools listed below... But it depends on the given font if it can be modified or not, so it is not you who is doing something wrong if it can't be modified.

- [embed](http://carnage-melon.tom7.org/embed/)
- [TTFPATCH](http://www.derwok.de/downloads/ttfpatch/)
- [FontUtils](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=FontUtils#fb138857)

If you really can't use any of these methods, choose an other font. (Or as a last approach, you could ignore SEO aspects by using images instead of fonts. Or ignore IE9 users.)

Good luck! :)